# Most appropriate way to select first occurrence of a child element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, traversal

I have a list like so:

```
<ul id="topElement">
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  <li>
```

Using jQuery, what is the best aka most efficient way to reference the *first* occurrence of a ul from #topElement.

That is to say, I do not want this...

```
$("#topElement ul")
```

Which will return every ul element in the tree.  I only want the first ul down.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that if you want the first "ul" you find inside the contents of the "ul" called "topElement", then you'd want this:

```
$('ul#topElement ul:first')
```

Comment: why ul#topElement? id is unique. #topElement should be faster.

Comment: You're right of course, but sometimes I do that just to help myself not be confused. It's not necessary, and in fact it can come back and bite you if you change your markup a lot. In this case I think I was just trying to make clear how the solution related to the problem posed. I doubt there's any measurable performance difference, however, as sizzle knows exactly what you know about the semantics of an "id" value :-)

Comment: It does what it says on the box.  :)

Answer (score 1):

$("#topElement ul").first();

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul#topElement:first")
```

Comment: I don't think that's right - he wants the first "ul" underneath the top "ul".

Answer (score 0):

`$("#topElement > li > ul:first")`